# Regex find text (A) or A) at beginning of line only w/ twist

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking for a regex that works to find the phrases "(A)" or "A)" only at the beginning of a line, and then replace the carriage return before it.

```
Example text 
Lots of words
A) Words
```

Replaced text:

```
Lots of words|REPLACEMENT|A) Words
```

My current closest is using

```
\r\n[(A)|A)| A)]
```

replaced with `","\1` - it misses the parenthesis after the A in just about every use case.

Comment: And what have you attempted to achieve the same?

Comment: @CinCout I've tried all kinds of variants using \r\n etc - but unfortuantely I'm rediculously bad at regex and struggle - I've tried using [] and a few other methods, but can't figure out how to only target the carriage return above it, or to target the text as well, and replace with the correct variant of only that text

Comment: But what is the expression? What is there to *fix*? Please post at least one attempt for us to explain where it went wrong.

Comment: Post your best attempt(s) so that someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: My current closest is using \r\n[(A)|A)| A)] replaced with ","\1 - it misses the paranthesis after the A in just about every use case

Comment: Kindly edit your question to post your attempt instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\r\n[(A)|A)| A)]` expression matches a CRLF line ending that is followed with 1 char that is either `(`, `A`, `)`, `|` or space. There is no group and `\1` is empty.

You may use the following regex:

**Find What**: `\R(\(?[A-Z]\))`
**Replace With**: `|replacement|$1`

**Details**:

- `\R` - a line break (that is, it matches `\r\n`, or `\r`, or `\n`)
- `(\(?[A-Z]\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(?` - an optional `(`
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
  - `\)` - a `)`

[image]

Comment: Selecting as answer - thanks a ton for both the answer, and the explanation to help explain how it works, as that is really helpful for learning too!

Comment: @NRGdallas Please also check the information on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Remember that adding `[...]` around your non-working patterns is almost never a correct fix.